# Meta data retrieve issue using ANT Tool

Tags: ant, salesforce

I am facing an error stating as **“Build Failed: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out”** while retrieving the data in ANT tool deployment in salesforce.

Note: I have given correct username, password and security token.
I could retrieve data in my personal lap and if i do the same in the office i am facing the above error.

Could any one help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a salesforce configuration problem and not an ANT issue. Where do you store credentials? I'm guessing the values are different on the two machines explaining why it works on your laptop.

Comment: Increasing noiselevel  => ant -f foobar.xml -debug to get  more details / the whole stacktrace might be useful.

Comment: I stored credentials in build.properties file & i am giving the same values on both the machines. I couldn't understand what would be the problem

Comment: @Rebse I am not familiar in ANT. Could you please tell how to give noiselevel command and also i would like to know meaning of noiselevel=>ant -f foobar.xml.                                                  
if you have any related info kindly share

Comment: How do you start your ant script ? ant -f foobar.xml -debug is the syntax for starting your script named foo.xml from commandline/shell, the -debug parameter tells ant to use loglevel debug.

Comment: @Rebse i ran with the same command and i got error stating(Buildfile: foobar.xml does not exist!)Build failed

Comment: You have to adapt the snippet to your needs, almost sureley your buildfile.xml dosn't spell 'foobar.xml' ;-)